# How to output a single print statement out of many and redirect the rest to null in python

Tags: python, stdout, timeit

I have a file with say 3 print statements, all necessary. Something like this,

```py
def method1(n: int, m: int, matrix: list) -> list:
    for i in range(m):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            for j in range(n):
                print(str(matrix[i][j]), end=" ") # <-- 1
        else:
            for j in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
                print(str(matrix[i][j]), end=" ") # <-- 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from timeit import timeit

    matrix = [[10, 20, 30, 40], [15, 15, 25, 55], [17, 19, 17, 18], [1, 8, 9, 2]]
    print(timeit(lambda: method1(4, 4, matrix), number=10000))  # <-- 3
```

Now I have similar files in a large project and I want to check the time it takes the for each method to run hence only `3` is required and rest aren't, but if I run all of the files in the directory `print` statements like `1` and `2` create a lot of clutter combined with similar redundant `print` statements from other files.

**What have I tried?**

1. `return` statements wherever I could but then let's say there are methods where I encounter statements like,

```py
if something:
   print(ans)
   ans += 1
```

where swapping `print` with `return` would just not work.

2. `yield` function, well it creates a generator function which basically would work but it would tamper with the result of `timeit` module
3. `#` single line commenting, it was the best approach but then if I comment the lines `1` and `2` then the method breaks.
4. Writing a function which redirects the output to null and passing every file's unnecessary `print` statement through it.

Comment: you can't create empty loop - you have to use at least `pass` in loop when you use `#`.

Comment: you can open some file ie. `fh = open("name", "w") `and use `print(..., file=fh)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps set `sys.stdout` to `/dev/null` during the `timeit`?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVLRboMwDHznK06dJkAKK9BW69DYjyAUMZGuqUhAIV3Xr2cm0LK97GWWTokvts@x3F3tsdWbfWeGoRYHKEF@nQQ6g9SWQd3Oyhr5laGRvQ0RvblL5oHs0BpIioKp9IcIVDjRo8kDvTwiRZ4jXuhb1mnJ0uHv59E6Q9JBb00wqReyLE5lyCB0na@wCvGA1yhCcs8UTS/@lgGFM0QO/5BMPc@jz3GuKyU4H/@34lxVUnO@msdiWgUrlZAWUnWtsbPnXmemv/ae8yc55CiKJGZICRvCNi4ZimTHMCIl7HaOeSbmhTCee8cw7BmISsvSVext3Z4tVSSNp8lx/EXaI9pO6MBf1@Jzrc9N4zP4Fz9E1f@IXqYzVpl6D5pKvddVdt@TLfV42w4akz6rd2HyJCYLpzbu9cZWljamSdMuzRPdeMPwDQ)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from timeit import timeit
    import sys

    matrix = [[10, 20, 30, 40], [15, 15, 25, 55], [17, 19, 17, 18], [1, 8, 9, 2]]
    stdout = sys.stdout
    with open('/dev/null', 'w') as sys.stdout:
        t = timeit(lambda: method1(4, 4, matrix), number=10000)
    sys.stdout = stdout
    print(t)  # <-- 3
```